# Low level SQL query

Tags: sql

[The tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWfAW.png)

Write an SQL query to list all the TraineeIds, names and emails of trainees who have not submitted any of the required assessments.

My attempt:

```
SELECT TraineeId
,      fname
,      lname
,      e-mail
FROM   Trainee T
,      assessment A
,      submissions S
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (A.assessmentId = S.assessmentId AND A.courseId = S.courseId) 
   AND T.traineeId = S.traineeId;
```

I'm not quite sure about this problem. The code is an attempt at finding the intersection between the two tables.

In addition, create a query that deducts 5% for submissions that are late

- Would it go along the lines: WHERE A.submissionDeadline > S.submissionDate;

Note: This is from a practise exam that there are no solutions for; it is not homework.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should use `Join x ON ..` syntax, instead of comma separated tables. As is, your table `A` is not joined. Also, `not exists` requires a query. Stating `where not exists (1=2 and 3=4)` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Might solve your problem

```
SELECT 
     T.TraineeId, T.fname, T.lname, T.e-mail
FROM 
     Trainee T, 
join  
    submissions S 
on 
    T.TraineeID = S.TraineeID 
join 
    assessment A
on
    S.AssessmentId=A.AssessmentId
WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `TraineeId`, `fName`, `lName`, `email`
FROM trainee T
WHERE TraineeId NOT IN (
  SELECT S.TraineeId 
  FROM submissions S, assessment A
  WHERE A.assessmentId = S.assessmentId 
  AND A.courseId = S.courseId
  AND A.submissionDeadline >= S.submissionDate)
```

Comment: I understand now :). Looks like my logic was close just my use of keywords. Thanks very much.